# onLoad Function Keep Reloading Page Continuesly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onload

Good Day,
I Have this Code that suppose to submit a form Once the Page Load, The error here is that it keeps submitting the form continuously.

**HTML BODY CODE**

```
<body onLoad="submitform();">
```

**Authomatic Submit Function**

```
    <script>
function submitform()
{
document.getElementById("gsend").submit();
}
```

**HTML FORM**

```
<FORM id="gsend" NAME="gsend" METHOD="POST" ACTION="index.php">
     <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="long" ID="long" VALUE="" hidden>
     <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="lat" ID="lat" VALUE="" hidden>


     </FORM>
```

**THE JAVASCRIPT IS THE GET THE CURRENT LOCATION OF A USER WHEN THE PAGE LOADS WHICH IS SUCCESSFUL**

```
<script>
   
   function initGeolocation()
     {
        if( navigator.geolocation )
        {
           // Call getCurrentPosition with success and failure callbacks
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( success, fail );
        }
        else
        {
           alert("Sorry, your browser does not support geolocation services.");
        }
     }

     function success(position)
     {

         document.getElementById('long').value = position.coords.longitude;
         document.getElementById('lat').value = position.coords.latitude
     }

     function fail()
     {
        // Could not obtain location
     }

   
</script>
```

**THE ISSUE HERE IS THE CODE KEEPS RELOADING .
I NEED HELP GUYS**

Comment: You are submitting the page onload, so of cause it loads continuesly

Comment: I want it to execute Once

Comment: Submit the page to another page, e.g. <form id="gsend" name="gsend" method="post" action="loc_result.php">

Comment: unclear what the form submission and the geo location code have in common. Are you just trying to save the location to the db? Seems like an Ajax/Fetch call would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the `<form>`, store the location to cookies

`index.php` check if cookie contain `lat`

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['lat']){
  // cookie exist
  // do stuff
}
```

you can replace `<body onLoad="submitform();">` with `window.onload` and remove the form, so just write `<body>`

`script.js` check also the cookie

```
window.onload = (event) => {
  // check if cookie not exist
  if (!document.cookie.includes('lat=')) {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail);
    }
    else {
      alert("Sorry, your browser does not support geolocation services.");
    }
  }
  else {
    // nothing here, cookie exist 
    // index.php should read the cookie for location and serve the content
  }
};


function success(position) {
  // set the cookies
  document.cookie = 'long=' + position.coords.longitude; + '; expires=Sun, 1 Jan 2023 00:00:00 UTC; path=/'
  document.cookie = 'lat=' + position.coords.latitude + '; expires=Sun, 1 Jan 2023 00:00:00 UTC; path=/'
  
  // reload the page and tell index.php to read the location inside cookies
  window.location.reload();
}

function fail() {
  alert("Sorry, you did not allow us to get geolocation services.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a fetch call to send the data tot he server instead of having to submit the whole page.

```
function initGeolocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    // Call getCurrentPosition with success and failure callbacks
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail);
  } else {
    alert("Sorry, your browser does not support geolocation services.");
  }
}

function success(position) {
  const data = {
    latitude: position.coords.latitude
    longitude: position.coords.longitude
  };

  fetch('index.php', {
      method: 'POST'
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
    .then(function (response) {
       console.log('sent');
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
}

function fail() {
  // Could not obtain location
}
```